# jquery checkbox checked change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

If checkbox is clicked then value of checkbox must be 1. If checkbox is not clicked then its value must be 0. For some reason below code seems not working fine.

```js
// Checkbox values 1/0.
$("#prefForm").submit(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.is(":checked")) {
      self.val('1');
    } else {
      self.val('0');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-activity">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!-- <input type="hidden" name="donate_buskie" value=""> -->
      <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-1' class='pseudo-checkbox sr-only' name="donate_buskie" value="0" />
      <label for='checkbox-1' class='glyphicon-check-click fancy-checkbox-label'><span><?php echo JText::_('When someone donates to my Buskie'); ?></span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <input type="hidden" name="receives_donation" value=""> -->
      <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-2' class='pseudo-checkbox sr-only' name="receives_donation" value="0" />
      <label for='checkbox-2' class='glyphicon-check-click fancy-checkbox-label'><span><?php echo JText::_('When someone receives a donation'); ?></span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-3' class='pseudo-checkbox sr-only' name="comment_buskie" value="0" />
      <label for='checkbox-3' class='glyphicon-check-click fancy-checkbox-label'><span><?php echo JText::_('When someone posts a comment on your Buskie'); ?></span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-4' class='pseudo-checkbox sr-only' name="comment_reply" value="0" />
      <label for='checkbox-4' class='glyphicon-check-click fancy-checkbox-label'><span><?php echo JText::_('When someone replies to my comment'); ?></span>
</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You code snippet works fine!

Comment: What's the point of this code? It goes against the standard pattern for working with checkboxes in that if the box is not checked then no value will be sent in the request. Therefore the value being `0` when unchecked is moot. If you want to know which checkboxes are/are not checked it would make far more sense to use `map()` to create a boolean array of the checked state of each checkbox

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use jQuery to assign 1/0 values for a checkbox, based on wether it is checked or not. The checkbox already holds a boolean value. If you **need** ones and zeros, you can just use

```
var number_value = self.val() ? 1 : 0;
```